# Changing a tag from favorite to ignored using tag dropdown removes the tag from favourites but doesn't add it to ignored

Tags: feature-request, bug, tags, tag-watching, ignored-tags

I noticed today that when I changed a tag from favorite to ignored, the tag is removed from the favorites but is not added to ignored tags

[image]

As in the screenshot. I changed the [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) tag from favorite to ignored using then tag dropdown and the tag is immediately removed from the favorite tag but is not added to ignored tag (until I refresh the page). Also, the [Color theme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22184/what-do-the-colors-on-stack-overflow-mean) has changed from favourite to normal but not to ignored. Why is that?

Also, Changing the tag from ignored to favourite will remove it from the ignored tags list but will not add it to the favourite tags list. The color theme will also change to normal but not to favourite (until the Page is refreshed).

Is this a bug or is this by-design?. If it is by-design, Can it be changed?

Comment: Also, marking it as favorite again will neither add it to the list nor color the questions again. (until refresh of course)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Yeah. Noticed that too. Editing it into the post

Comment: The bug can be simplified: it's never adding to favorite/ignored list, just removing. (might be by design)